# Redirect page with url varibles in tact

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

I'm looking for an easy solution to redirect a user from page:

```
http://www.domain.com/page.aspx?Xvarible=1&Yvarible=2
```

to the new location:

```
http://www.domain.com/newfolder/page.aspx?Xvarible=1&Yvarible=2
```

It is a single page that needs be redirected, but the variables can change dynamically.

So I need to be able to catch all the variables and redirect them to the new location using ASP.NET and C#

Any help?

Comment: Use `Request.QueryString["variable"].Value` to extract variables and `Response.Redirect("~/newfolder/page.aspx?Xvariable=" + var1 + "&Yvariable=" + var2);` to redirect. I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to do. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Is this page always going to be redirected, as in a permanent redirect?

Comment: @TestWell we don't always know what the variable names are. One time it could be Variable=1 another it could Variable1278873=1

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("domain2.com/folder2/page2.aspx?" + Request.QueryString.ToString());
```

@TestWell: don't forget to urlencode if you're building your own querystring

Comment: Just did some research, and yes I should be using `UrlEncode`. Never heard of it before, cheers.